# How can I get a reference to the TFS WorkItem in a WorkItemChangedEvent?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-events

Seems like this would be super simple, but I'm struggling to find what I need.

I'm implementing a TFS 2013 event handler and simply want to get a reference to the Work Item that raised the change event. It seems easy enough to get the title, but I can't find a property or method in the event signature objects that gives me either a reference to the WorkItem object or the information I'd need to go query it (e.g. the ID).

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
         TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, 
         NotificationType notificationType, 
         object notificationEventArgs, 
         out int statusCode, 
         out string statusMessage, 
         out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
    {          
        var ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
        string WorkItemTitle = ev.WorkItemTitle; /* easy enough */

        /*********** need help with this bit *********/
        int ChangedWorkItemID = ???
              OR
        WorkItem ChangedWorkItem= ???
    }
```

**Note:** this code has been stripped down to bare bones to make it easier to read and focus on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this. It isn't as elegant as I'd like, but it works. I'm definitely interested if anyone has a better answer.

Here's what worked for the benefit of anyone else with the same question.

You can get the Work Item's ID from the `CoreFields.IntegerFields` collection on the `notificationEventArgs` (of type `WorkItemChangedEvent`) passed into the event handler. Using that you can get the `WorkItem` from the `WorkItemStore`'s `GetWorkItem` method.

Note: The item you want has a field name of "ID", and it appears that it is always element 0 in the collection, but I didn't trust that always to be true so I searched on the name property using LINQ just in case. Here's a code snippet of the whole affair.

```
IntegerField idField =  ev.CoreFields.IntegerFields
                          .Where<IntegerField>(field => field.Name.Equals("ID"))
                          .FirstOrDefault<IntegerField>();

int WorkItemID=  idField.NewValue;

//Assuming you have an initialized WorkItemStore Object here
 workItemStore.GetWorkItem(WorkItemID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID by using the following code:

```
// Get the ID of the work item that was just changed by the user.
int workItemId = ev.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0].NewValue;
```

Without having to connect to the project or the workitem store. It's a little bit simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are getting in the event is only some of the core fields and the changed values.  At the beginning of your event handler do this

```
Uri projectCollectionUri = new Uri(settings.TFSServerURL + projectCollectionFolder);
TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri);
WorkItemStore wiStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

So notice the settings.TFSServerURL this is in the app.config that goes with the DLL.  I was using two TFS server, but you can potentially *cough* hard code the TFS Url *cough* after you do those 3 lines, you can now do this

```
eventWorkItem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(workItemId);
```

This will give you access to the full work items with all it's property.

To access fields other than the core field access them this way for example

```
eventWorkItem.Fields["Activity Date"].Value
```

Comment: The trouble with this answer is that it assumes I have the workItemId. I know how to get a work item with that information. The question is about getting that far.

Comment: Which you figured out in you self answer.  You have to cast it as a WorkItemChangedEvent. to get intellisence and property mapping.